# Array allocation of SWIG C++ type from Python

Tags: c++, python, swig, ctypes

I'm writing a python script for a program that has exposed its C++ API using SWIG.
A SWIG exposed function has an interface like this:

```
void writePixelsRect(JoxColor* colors, int left, int top, int width, int height);
```

JoxColor is a POD struct looking like this:

```
struct JoxColor {
    float r, g, b, a;
};
```

I can easily create a single JoxColor in Python and invoke a call to writePixelsRect like this:

```
c = JoxApi.JoxColor()
c.r = r
c.g = g
c.b = b
c.a = a
JoxApi.writePixelsRect(c, x, y, 1, 1)
```

Repeatedly calling writePixelsRect with a 1x1 pixel rectangle is very slow so I want to create an array of JoxColor from python so I can write bigger rectangles at the time. Is this possible with SWIG types?

Note that I don't have access to the source code for the C++ library exposing JoxColor and writePixelsRect so I can't add a help function for this. I also don't want to introduce new C++ code in the system since it would force the users of my python script to compile the C++ code on whatever platform they are running. I do have access to ctypes in the python environment so if I could somehow typecast a float array created in ctypes to the type of JoxColor* for SWIG it would work for me.

Comment: Is it possible for you to modify the SWIG wrapping part?

Comment: Do you have access to *.swig file? Could you check if it includes any functionalities from SWIG libraries like cpointer.i, carrays.i or cmalloc.i - http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html. Maybe someone that prepared this SWIG wrapper already included there functionality of handling array of JoxColor? You could also check JoxAPImodule.py file for list of all available function and classes.

Comment: I don't have access to the swig files and I'm not able to modify the SWIG wrapping part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kinda tricky, but could you, at least for this part of the code, use a pure-ctypes solution?  Basically manually look at the symbols exported by the shared libary file to find the name that the writePixelsRect function was exported as.  C++ does name mangling, so while it might just be `writePixelsRect` if the library authors chose to make it `extern "C"`, it might be something much messier, like `_Z15writePixelsRectP8JoxColoriiii` (that's how it was exported in a dummy C++ library I just created on my system).

On Linux, this command should tell you the symbol name:

```
nm libjox.so | grep writePixel | cut -d " " -f 3
```

Then, save that string and insert it into Python code kinda like this:

```
from ctypes import *

LIBRARY_NAME = 'libjox.so'
c = cdll.LoadLibrary(LIBRARY_NAME)

WIDTH = 20
HEIGHT = 20

class JoxColor(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("r", c_float), ("g", c_float), ("b", c_float), ("a", c_float)]

ColorBlock = JoxColor * (WIDTH * HEIGHT)

data_array = ColorBlock()

color = JoxColor(0, 0, 1, 0)
for i in range(WIDTH * HEIGHT):
    data_array[i] = color

c._Z15writePixelsRectP8JoxColoriiii(data_array, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
```

Assuming that `_Z15writePixelsRectP8JoxColoriiii` is the symbol that the function is accessible as in the shared library.  Running this code just worked on my system with a dummy library like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct JoxColor {
    float r, g, b, a;
};

void writePixelsRect(JoxColor *colors, int left, int top, int width, int height) {
    int p = 0;
    printf("size: %i, %i\n", width, height);
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            JoxColor color = colors[p];
            printf("pixel: %f, %f, %f, %f\n", color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a);
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm hopeful that it's not too far from working code in your environment.

Comment: Also, if you want to run this test, the above library code should treated as C++, not C, to replicate the name mangling (I just detest writing C++).  In other words, save in a ".cpp" file and compile with g++.

Comment: I'm not sure how it is on Linux but on Windows I think that module doesn't export all functions/methods that it provide to Python. It export only one function called PyInit_modulename or initmodulename and through this function it calls everything else. I think that you cannot import writePixelsRect directly using ctypes, because it isn't there.

Comment: Thanks. I do indeed have access to the original c++ api functions but I didn't consider them because of the mangling. However I can keep the swig based code as a fallback for platforms where I don't manage to figure out the mangled symbol name :)

Answer (score 0):

Barring special typemaps, this SWIG prototype

```
void writePixelsRect(JoxColor* colors, int left, int top, int width, int height);
```

means that `colors` is a single object of type `JoxColor`, not an array. The fact that your call with just a single object works (albeit slowly) suggests that that's true. So passing an array is likely to just give you a type mismatch error from the SWIG wrapper code.

But honestly, this looks like a function that writes an arbitrarily-large rectangle. So if you want to draw a larger rectangle (of one color) just pass in a larger width and/or height:

```
JoxApi.writePixelsRect(c, x, y, 10, 20)
```

**Edit:**
I didn't realize you were writing the SWIG wrapper, I thought that was provided to you. In that case you can write a typemap that will convert a Python list (or tuple, or whatever you want) into JoxColor*.
The SWIG docs show an example for how turn a Python list-of-strings into char**: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn59
The typemap uses Python C APIs to do the conversion, you can use anything the Python docs say. Essentially you allocate a JoxColor array then iterate over the Python list object and use `PyList_GetItem` to get each individual object. That will return a SWIG-wrapped PyObject, you can use `SWIG_ConvertPtr(list_item_py_object, (void**)&joxcolor_ptr, $descriptor(JoxColor *), 0)` to convert that into a pointer to your actual JoxColor element. Then you can copy that into your array.

Remember that a typemap for `JoxColor*` will apply everywhere `JoxColor*` appears, you can say `JoxColor* colors` to specialize it to just this case.

FYI, by default SWIG wraps JoxColor*, JoxColor&, JoxColor, and JoxColor[] in exactly the same way, as a single object. Python only has objects, it doesn't know of pointers/references/arrays (Python lists are also objects). http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn22

Comment: It's one way of interpreting the API, but not what it does. It does take a pointer to a set of pixels and copies them into the target image in the rectangle specified. The most likely reason it wasn't properly mapped to SWIG is that it's a huge API and much of the SWIG:ing was done automatically and this function seems to need more attention to work all the way.

Comment: I didn't realize you were writing the SWIG wrapper yourself. See my edit.

Comment: I don't write my own SWIG wrapper. It's a big C++ API that has been more or less automatically been exposed as for python programmers using SWIG. I do have access to the C++ dll's but not not the SWIG files and it's not an option to change the actual wrapping code.